# How to pass a list of integers as json data to a Spring Boot rest API without a custom intermediate object?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

How to pass a list of integers as json data to a Spring Boot rest API without creating a custom intermediate object? I know you can create a DTO sort of object to map the request and I've done that successfully but is there a way to receive it as a collection/array of IDs without having to create a class just for this purpose? I tried to do it without any luck. Also tried to map it to a collection of the Entity the IDs refer to also without any luck. A way to do this, or alternatives that are more idiomatic to Spring Boot would be welcomed.

Sample of request body that's being sent to the endpoint:

```
{
    "products": [
        "1",
        "2"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Try with `Map<String, List<String>>`

Answer (score 2):

It seems answer of fps should be suitable, but here one caveat 
Even if your class is annotated as @RestController, you need to use @RequestBody when using Map as input (with POJO this annotation can be avoided) 
Bellow code works fine:

```
@PostMapping("/products")
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
public Object createProducts(@RequestBody Map<String, List<String>> input) {
    return input;
}
```

More agile way is using Jackson classes.
It allows to use not only Strings, but all "native" json structures. 
You can check JsonNode.isNumber(), JsonNode.isTextual(), JsonNode.isArray(), JsonNode.isObject() and so on.

```
@PostMapping("/products")
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
public Object createProducts(@RequestBody Map<String, JsonNode> input) {
    return input;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, didn't know about JsonNode.